# different shape of image and predicted mask in mmdetection 3.0, RTMdet model

Tags: instance, mask, image-segmentation

I've trained an RTMDet-ins model in mmdetection 3.0, and the predicted masks of the model is 0-4 pixels too small in the y-dimension.
Does anyone know what could be the possible cause of this?
Is it some scaling issue or what?

I haven't changed anything significant in the original training config. The predicted masks looks alright, there just 0-4 pixels too small in the y-dimension.

Comment: Too small compared to the image I should say, so the predicted mask dimension doesn't match the image dimension